# How to position arrows for this Tikz code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I need to draw an arrow between two predefined blocks in my flowchart. I know that if the blocks are not colinear, I can use '|-' to draw bended arrows but thats not working. Below is my code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
% Definition of blocks:

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2cm, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{adder} = [circle,minimum size=1em,text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 \begin{frame}
 \begin{center} 
 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2 cm]
 \draw [step=0.5cm,gray!30,very thin](-5.5,-2) grid (5,5);
 \node(ref.pnt) at (-5,3.4) [FIX]{};
 \node(b1) [block, right of=ref.pnt, xshift=-1.33cm] {B1};
 \node(b2) [s.block, right of=b1, xshift=0.3cm] {B2};
 \node(b3) [block, right of=b2, xshift=0.3cm] {B3};
 \node(b4) [block, right of=b3, xshift=0.8cm] {B4};
 \node(add) [adder, below right of=b4, xshift=0.0cm] {+};
 \node(b5) [block, below left of=add, xshift=-0.0cm] {B5};
 \node(b6) [block, left of=b5, xshift=-0.8cm] {B6};
 \node(b7) [s.block, left of=b6, xshift=-0.3cm] {B7};
 \node(b8) [s.block, below of=b7, xshift=-0.0cm] {B8};
 \node(b9) [block, left of=b7, xshift=-0.3cm] {B9};

 \draw [arrow] (b1) -- (b2);
 \draw [arrow] (b2) -- (b3);
 \draw [arrow] (b3) -- (b4);
 \draw [active.arrow] (b4)  |- (add);
 \draw [arrow] (add)  |- (b5);
 \draw [arrow] (b5)  -- (b6);
 \draw [arrow] (b6)  -- (b7);
 \draw [arrow] (b7)  -- (b9);
 \draw [arrow] (b9)  |- (b8);
 \draw [active.arrow] (b8)  |- (b6);
 \draw [active.arrow] (b6)  |- (b5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]
Green  arrows in above picture show the desired location. How can I specify the starting/ending locations for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\draw [arrow] (b4)  |- (add);
\draw [arrow] (b8)  |- (b6);
```

can be solved by simply switching `|-` to `-|`. But I don't know what to do to solve:

```
\draw [active.arrow] (b6)  |- (b5);
```

Comment: The problem with \draw [active.arrow] (b8)  -| (b6) is that it ends arrow at the mid-bottom point of b6. Since there are two arrows, one going in b6 from b8 and other going out from b6 to b5, I want them to be equally space around the mid-bottom point.

Comment: here we go: define reverse arrow `\tikzstyle{rarrow} = [thick,<-,>=stealth]` now `\draw [rarrow] (b6.south)++(-.5,0) |- (b8.east);` and `\draw [arrow] (b6.south)++(.5,0) |-  ++(0,-1.5)  -| (b5);`. I hope this solves your problem :>

Comment: Yes it did. Can you update your answer for future reference. Thank you.

Comment: btw: reverse arrow is necessary, because ++offset didn't work properly in forward direction

Answer (score 3):

Meanwhile @serial solve your problem (as you indicate), however, let be noted that your MWE hasn't defined all styles, which you are used in it ... so I for exercise rewrote your MWE on different way. See, if it can be useful in your future projects

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, chains, positioning, scopes}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{frame}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
               > = stealth,
   node distance = 2 cm and 0.5 cm,
     start chain = A going right,
    block/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=white,
                    text width=2cm, minimum height=1cm,
                    align=center,on chain=A},
   sblock/.style = {block, text width=1cm},
    adder/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=1em,
                    inner sep=1pt, node contents={\Large$+$}},
every join/.style = {thick},
    arrow/.style = {thick,->}
                    ]
%---
%\draw [step=0.5cm,gray!30,very thin] (-5.5,-2) grid (5,5);
%---
\node [block]               {B1};% node name: A-1
\node [sblock,join = by ->] {B2};
\node [block, join = by ->] {B2};
\node [sblock,join = by ->] {B4};
%
\node [block, below=of A-1] {B9};
\node [sblock,join = by <-] {B7};
\node [block, join = by <-] {B6};
\node [sblock,join = by <-] {B5};
%
\node [sblock, 
       below=1cm of A-6]    {B8};% node name: A-9
%
\node (add) [adder, right=of $(A-4.east)!0.5!(A-8.east)$];
%
    \begin{scope}[arrow]
\draw (A-4)  -| (add);
\draw (A-4)  |- (add);
\draw (add)  |- (A-8);
%
\draw (A-5)  |- (A-9);
\draw (A-9)  -| ([xshift=-3mm] A-7.south);
\draw ([xshift=3mm] A-7.south) |- (A-9 -| A-8) -- (A-8);    
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As you see, node naming I left to chain, using of join simplify drawing arrows between nodes, in styles for blocks I omit `minimum width`, which as you can see is superfluous to `minimum width`. With `scope[arrow]` you can spare writing of `[arrow]` at every `\draw` macro.

**Edit:**
I also correct all obsolete syntax of TikZ used in your MWE!

[image]